# php curl - reading only html codes

Tags: php, curl

php curl is reading style(css) files and downloading gifs,jpegs,pngs and everything. so curl is spending bandwith, and it is also taking times. actually i dont need images+css+etc. i only need to read html source codes..

well, is there a way to block images,css and other things while using php curl? so, curl works faster

Comment: If you are using curl to request 1 URL, it should only download what's at that URL ; can you show your code ? And are you sure it downloads the CSS/images ?

Comment: Please show some code. curl will usually download only the resource itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you point cURL at a URL of a website it will download only the source HTML. You have to manually fetch CSS, images and other attachments via additional cURL requests to each of the resources URLs.

If you are having performance issues with cURL, consider paralleling your requests using curl_multi_* functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php